# how to mimic Oracle's merge clause using mysql 'replace into' clause?

Tags: mysql

Here is one more related query on 'replace into' clause. I am trying to get following format the query like below using 'replace into'. 
Basically, trying to form Oracle's merge like query. But it fails with "SQL Error(1136): rows count doesn't match value count at row 1". Please suggest:

```
replace into vomdashboard_summary (select *
                                          from
                                              vomdashboard_summary_temp
                                          inner join vomdashboard_summary as vom_s
                                              on vomdashboard_summary_temp.VOMDASHBOARD_ID = vom_s.VOMDASHBOARD_ID
                                          and
                                              vom_s.manual is null)
```

Comment: Try without the `*` and replace it with the desired columns. As we don't know the structure of your tables, it's hard to answer more precisely.

Comment: Ya.. Thanks. This worked:replace into vomdashboard_summary (columnA, columnB, columnC)
    select
        temp.columnA, temp.columnB, temp.columnC
    from
        (select
             vomdashboard_summary_temp.*
         from
             vomdashboard_summary_temp
             inner join vomdashboard_summary as vom_s
                 on vomdashboard_summary_temp.VOMDASHBOARD_ID = vom_s.VOMDASHBOARD_ID
         where
             coalesce(vom_s.app_ready, 'No') != 'Yes'
        ) temp

Comment: Ya.. Thanks. This worked:replace into vomdashboard_summary (columnA, columnB, columnC)
    select
        temp.columnA, temp.columnB, temp.columnC
    from
        (select
             vomdashboard_summary_temp.*
         from
             vomdashboard_summary_temp
             inner join vomdashboard_summary as vom_s
                 on vomdashboard_summary_temp.VOMDASHBOARD_ID = vom_s.VOMDASHBOARD_ID
         where
             coalesce(vom_s.app_ready, 'No') != 'Yes'
        ) temp